# How does XML cross domain jquery AJAX parsing works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

Hi I tried parsing a XML file using AJAX method.It works fine when the XML file is on the local directory.But when I upload the xml to my web hosting it doesn't work.

After Googling I found about the cross domain policy.But the strange part is when I tried uploading the xml to my google drive and tried accessing it from there, It worked perfectly.Well how is that possible?

*PS: Im just a newbie to javascript*

Comment: I would assume that the Google drive response included CORS headers, which enables cross domain requests

Comment: Is it possible to grant permission in my server?

Comment: Yes, but not in JS. It has to be done on the server. Google 'CORS [your server side language here]'

Comment: you need to configure your server to append this header in it's response: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com`

Comment: The issue is at times xml file from google drive works...and at times it doesnt work at all :(